# Operate car lights using microprocessor and simplified wiring loom

Tags: automotive

I'm in the process of converting an old car from petrol to electric. Looking at the wiring loom (it's a mess!) each thing in the rear of the car has a +ve and -ve cable running from front to back. This seems wasteful to me. Would it be possible to have just three wires (from front to rear) (+ve, -ve and signal) and then send a specific signal to turn on e.g. rear lights, left indicator, fog lights etc and then use solid-state relays to operate those lights. This way, I could have just three wires running front to back in the car and then more wires as necessary branching off from the circuit board at the rear of the car?

Someone must have thought of this before, so maybe there's a good reason for *not* doing this?

Comment: I believe this question would also be a good fit for https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about automotive wiring and not about electronics design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Would it be possible to have just three wires (from front to rear)
>   (+ve, -ve and signal) and then send a specific signal to turn on e.g.
>   rear lights, left indicator, fog lights etc and then use solid-state
>   relays to operate those lights.*

That's pretty much what modern cars do. They use CAN bus and, for less critical control aspects tee-off to a LIN bus: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.aa1car.com/library/can_systems.htm).

Don't use SSRs though because they are not as reliable as high-side switches designed specifically for vehicles: -

[image]

High-side switches have the reliability and fail-safe protection built in and are designed for vehicle applications.

Answer (score 1):

Why three wires, and not just two?  V+ and Signal?  Unless the car is made of fiberglass or wood, you could use body sheet metal for ground.

This is going to take significant work, though.

- In order to control a signal line you will need a microprocessor at the signal send end, somewhere near the driver instrument panel.  You'll also need a second microprocessor at the rear of the vehicle to decode the signals.
- That's a crowded space to work. You'll probably have to pull the instrument panel to get easy access there.
- The microprocessor (send end) will have to include voltage regulator from 13.7v down to processor input voltage.  To be safe you should probably plan on 14.4 to 11v or so, and include protection incase somebody places jumper cables on the car in the wrong order.  That happens.
- You'll have to obtain inputs from the transmission or shift lever ( for reverse lamps)
- You'll have to obtain inputs for both left and right turn signals.
- You'll need to monitor lamp power as set by the user (on - off).
- You'll need to monitor brake pedal for brake lamps.
- You'll need to design a communications protocol so you can monitor the signals and react accordingly.
- You'll need the second microprocessor somewhere in the rear of the vehicle.  Obviously you'll have to i/o pin and provide solid state relays for illumination - on, brake light, reverse lamps and turn signals.
- You will still have to provide wiring from the rear microprocessor thru relays (minimum four) I'm assuming your vehicle has separate bulbs for turn signals and includes a high mount stop lamp.  If your vehicle uses left right brake lamps as turn signals, that requires some clever coding (think about the high mount stop lamp)
- If the ultimate goal is to reduce wiring, you could add a microprocessor at each tail lamp.
- You will have to decode the communications signals and react accordingly. And because brake lamp function is a significant safety item, you want to ensure you solution is very robust.
- And if you intend to haul a trailer (with two taillamp setup), that will a whole other series of design complications.

But yes, you'd be saving wire. No question.

Comment: "why not two wires only": you often really want your return current to flow the same path as your signal, especially over a longer distance on a car.

Comment: Right you are. Good catch. Low ampacity, twisted pair wire dedicated for signal. Sheet metal for power ground. Three wires it is.

Comment: "saving wire" - I think I would save by not buying all those fancy controllers...

Comment: @SolarMike well, if you want to have an sensor or actor somewhere, you'll need something at that point; and considering the ridiculous total cabling length of modern middle class cars, better bus design is kind of cost- and reliability critical.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, reliability and cost come to mind.

But the manufacturers tend to use the chassis and body as the return wire. If this is a fibreglass car then each bulb fitting will need a supply and earth or ground.

A supply wire to each lamp and a common return is simple and effective which is why it has been the most popular. The supply wires can then be color coded so the functions can be recognised easily. Citroen used numbers stamped into the insulation but that proves difficult to read with age...